# Virus changed some folders and files' extensions to .exe

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, virus, malware, file-extension

A virus changed all folders and some of files on my USB flash drive to .exe files. I scanned the flash drive with [USB Disk Security](http://download.cnet.com/USB-Disk-Security/3000-2239_4-10708708.html) and scanned my computer with Microsoft Security Essentials, deleting all detected malware, but the files and folders on my flash drive are still shown as .exe files. what can I do? I can't format my flash drive because it contains some important data.

Comment: did u check the hidden files ? usually these type of viruses hides the original files and create an exe file in the same name.. may be you can back up those data if you have..

Comment: The only true answer: Restore your important data from backup. ... The real answer: Go through it file by file, rename it and check it for consistency (doing a virus scan and checking the contents by hand).

Comment: @AthibaN : I Select 'show hidden file and folders' and no more file or folder shows.but when I try to remove .exe postfix it's alert me that exist a folder with this name.

Comment: Uncheck the `Hide protected Operating System Files` option